# Project Euler - Problem No.4 - Largest palindrome product

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge, palindrome

according to the problem:

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>   Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

Here is my code:

```
def largest_palindrome_product(n:int) -> int:
    '''
    Returns largest palindrome whose a product of two n digit(base 10) integer
    :param n: the number of digits in the numbers we compute the product of
    :return: largest palindrome whose a product of two n digit(base 10) integer or -1 if non were found
    '''
    # Dealing with edge cases
    if n == 1:
        return 9
    elif n < 1:
        raise ValueError("Expecting n to be >= 1")

    mul_max = -1
    upper_boundary = (10**n) - 1
    lower_boundary = 10**(n-1)

    # Searching for the largest palindrome between the upper boundary and the lower one.
    for i in range(upper_boundary, lower_boundary, -1):
        for j in range(i, lower_boundary, -1):
            str_prod = str(i*j)
            if i*j > mul_max and str_prod[::-1] == str_prod:
                mul_max = i*j

    return mul_max
```

Here is a small test case for this code:

```
from ProjectEuler.problem4 import largest_palindrome_product

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # largest prime product is of 91*99 -> returns 9009
    print(largest_palindrome_product(2))
    # Checking edge cases -> returns 9
    print(largest_palindrome_product(1))
    # largest prime product is of 993*913 -> returns 906609
    print(largest_palindrome_product(3))
```

Let me know your thoughts on this solution :)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit.  You cannot incorporate information from any answers (below) into your question, as this invalidates the answers.  See [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), especially the "what should I **_not_** do" section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Errors

`range(start, end)` goes from the `start` value, inclusive, to the `end` value, exclusive.  So

```
for i in range(upper_boundary, lower_boundary, -1):
```

will not include `lower_boundary` in the values which will be tested, so you will be ignoring products where `i` would be `10` (two digit case) and `100` (three digit case).

Similarly, `for j in range(i, lower_boundary, -1)` will ignore products where `j` would be `10` and `100`.

The solution is to use `range(..., lower_boundary - 1, -1)`.

### Special Case

Why is `n == 1` special cased, to return `9`?  Why don’t you trust the algorithm to return the correct value?  Oh, right, `9*1` wouldn’t be tested, because `lower_boundary = 1`, and got excluded due to the bug above.

Perhaps you should have examined this special case closer.

### Optimizations

You compute `i*j` up to 3 times each loop.  You should compute it once, and store it in a variable, such as `prod`.

```
        prod = i * j
        str_prod = str(prod)
        if prod > mul_max and str_prod[::-1] == str_prod:
            mul_max = prod
```

You are searching in decreasing ranges for the outer and inner loops.  Why?  True: You’ll find the target value faster.  But you still search all product values where `j <= i`.  Is there any way of determining there won’t be any larger `mul_max` value, either from the inner loop, or from the outer loop, or both?  For instance, if `i*j > mul_max` is not true, would it be true for any **smaller** value of `j`?

Turning a integer into a string is an \$O(\log n)\$ operation.  Can you skip doing it for every product?

```
    for j in range(i, lower_boundary - 1, -1):
        prod = i * j

        if prod <= mul_max:
           break

        str_prod = str(prod)
        if str_prod[::-1] == str_prod:
            mul_max = prod
```

Can something similar be done with the `for i in range(...)` loop, to speed things up even further?